# AWS RDS Table access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Can anyone please help me to resolve this?

How we can provide access to a group on a table in databses instead of providing access to every single users?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your need, I would create a group in IAM with a policy giving access to the RDS table. Then add the users you need to that group.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.IAMPolicy.html

Comment: Just curious, can you use IAM policy to limit access to a specific table in a Database? Or is it for Database only?

Comment: My understanding is that you cannot do that, it is for the whole database.